# Create many to many relationship between facts

Tags: ssas

I have two facts tables facturesAvoirs and F_achat , How Create many to many relationship between facts?

[image]

Comment: What are the primary keys on facturesAvoirs and F_achat?

Comment: @DougClutter I update my question

Comment: You already have a many to many relationship between these tables. The V_Reception_... table is acting as a junction table (a.k.a. - cross-reference table).  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Why do you need to create a relationship between two facts?   Facts relate to dimensions, not to each other.